# Tizen wearable app: tizen wearable exposes his heartmonitor's service?

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I'm new in tizen world and in particular in the tizen wearable one. I wonder this thing : - galaxy gear s has a heart monitor sensor - android smartphone device can access and reads it (I don't know how, i only read that is possible)
But is possible to use the galaxy gear s how heart band and make this service directly accessible from the external without a smartphone ?
For example is possible to make this service readable by a gym's byke ?

THanks to everyone and sorry for the strange question.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the heart rate monitor inside a Tizen Wearable app using the monitor API.  You can then transmit that data over wifi, cell network, or BT LE to any device that might be listening.

Comment: 's Thanks :) Therefore without an Tizen Wearable app the smartwatch doesn't expose his monitor service (like POlar band ) to the external, right ? Could you suggest to me some guide/tutorial to do what you told to me in your post ?  Sorry if I bother you :(

Comment: Start at the Samsung dev site for Gear - http://developer.samsung.com/gear. Then download and install the Tizen SDK for Wearable. This has a custom version of Eclipse in it. It also has all the JavaScript wrappers for the sensor classes. Some of the samples that ship with the SDK show how to handle sensors. If you want to ship the data to the phone, you'll need the Accessory SDK on the Android side. If you have a web service already accepting data, you can use HttpRequest directly on the watch if you're connected by wifi or cell network.

Comment: Eric Cloninger thanks :) A last question : now I create a simple app that show heart rate on galaxy gear s screen. I understand that I can send this data through bluetooth to other device. But I have a doubt :
- is possible to use galaxy gear like peripheral and change the bluetooth service and characteristic exposes by galaxy gear s  ? LIke can we do on android lollipop with bluetoothgattserver :)
- is strictly necessary use the Accessory SDK on the android ?

Comment: Is possible to set , in tizen wearable app, a new bluetooth service with some characteristic to advertise ?

Sorry, but you are the only one that is answering me on this argument..

Comment: If the watch and the phone speak the same profile, you may use them if you want to handle all the hard work. I don't have a sample of this though. Accessory tries to insulate the protocol for developers so you don't have to worry about the profiles. I'm not very familiar with Bluetooth, though, so I can't answer your second question.